# Integers which are writable as a special type of sums and differences of square numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Are the following conjectures true?:

**(a)** For every integer $n$ there exist a number $k=2^q$ (for some positive integer $q$) and positive integers $n_1,\cdots,n_k$ such that 
$$
n=n_1^2+\cdots+n^2_{\frac{k}{2}}-(n^2_{\frac{k}{2}+1}+\cdots+n^2_k).
$$
Now, denote by $k(n)$ the least $k$ obtained from (a) (if it is true).

**(b)** The set of all $k(n)$, where $n$ runs over all integers, is unbounded above.

Comment: (b) is definitely false: [Lagrange's four-squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) says that every integer can be written as the sum of four squares, and hence every integer can be written as you wish with $k=8$, just by taking $n_5=\cdots=n_8=1$, say. Now [some numbers require one of the four squares to equal $0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem#Uniqueness), but you can surely get around that by giving yourself some leeway in choosing $n_5,\dots,n_8$.

Comment: Every integer that isn't $2\bmod4$ can be written as a difference of two squares. Every integer that is $2\bmod4$ can be written as the difference (or sum) of two integers that aren't.

Comment: Thanks Gerry. Please note that here  $n_i\neq 0$,  and the Lagrange's four-squares theorem is usable for natural numbers, clearly.

Comment: I'm sure it's not hard to handle zeros.

Comment: @Gerry. I'm not agree with you. The most difficulty comes from $n_i\neq 0$ (if $n_i>0$ is replaced by $n_i\geq 0$, then it is easy to solve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1=3^2+3^2-(4^2+1^2).$$ If $n$ is a square, say, $n=k^2$, then $$n=(3k)^2+(3k)^2-((4k)^2+k^2).$$ If $n$ is not a square, and is not $2\bmod4$, then there exist $r,s$ such that $$n=r^2-s^2;$$ moreover, $s\ne0$ since $n$ is not a square. If $n=4k+2\ge6$, then $4k-1=r^2-s^2$ for some nonzero $r,s$, so  $$n=r^2+2^2-(s^2+1^2).$$ Finally, $$2=3^2+1^2-(2^2+2^2).$$